Embedding Excel into form behavior
I'm encountering an issue when creating an Excel OLE object from Delphi.
Initially, everything functions correctly: I can change sheets and read/write cell values.
However, when I set the parent of the Excel window to a Delphi form, I experience unexpected behavior.
File options like saving and printing become disabled, and the main title bar changes from the "file name - Excel" to just "Excel."
Also switching sheets, settings cell values cause errors.
The only way to restore normal functionality is by double-clicking a cell on the sheet.
Is there any way to refresh it from code not by double click?
ExcelApp := CreateOleObject('Excel.Application');
ExcelApp.Visible := False; 
workbook := ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(FileName);

Worksheet := Workbook.WorkSheets[1];
Worksheet.Select;//works

Windows.SetParent(fExcelHandle, Panel1.Handle);
ShowWindow(fExcelHandle, SW_SHOW);

Worksheet := Workbook.WorkSheets[1];
Worksheet.Select; //return error

Worksheet := Workbook.WorkSheets[1]; //double cell click
Worksheet.Select; //works


May I ask what you ultimately want to achieve? Setting the parent of an Excel window to a Delphi form spontaneously feels like a very odd thing to be doing, and it almost feels expected that things could go wrong then. Maybe there is a different way to solve the thing you really want to achieve. What is that thing, if I may ask?

I definitely do not expect this to work at all. What makes you think it could work?

The goal is to allow user to compare data between app and excel and some of them have problems with when excel is open as standalone window.

@ David Heffernan It work almost as required, except that only one problem with setting active workbook that needed to be set by double click on the sheet.

If you're going to resort to trickery, then a safer trick might perhaps be to move the Excel window to a position outside of the visible screen area? Then it also wouldn't be a (visible) standalone window. ... But, can it really be such a problem to have a visible standalone Excel window? I imagine that Excel is designed to have its own specific main window and any tampering with that can have unforeseen consequences. Not saying that it's impossible, but it seems quite unlikely to work and to be safe.

By the way, how do you get the fExcelHandle? By looking globally for a window with the known class name of Excel main windows? A known problem is that there's no way to find a certain instance of Excel, if many are running. Even if you would make this solution work, I'm afraid you wouldn't be able to know which one out of several running Excel instances that you'd "capture".

The main problem is that you can't just set parent of another application window to be a window of your own application. Why? Because by doing so you are essentially introducing multi-threading into UI. By default your application is accessing its Windows only from within the scope of your application main thread. Same goes for Excel. But ass soon as you set parent of the Excel  to a widow that belongs to your application both your application main thread as well as Excel main thread are accessing the same window which can cause all sort of problems.

Another trick might be to just position Excel's window exactly over your Delphi application, using MoveWindow(fExcelHandle, Left, Top, Width, Height, True). Maybe do that on a timer (say, ever 200 ms), to keep it in place all the time. Or do it in an OnMove event handler (procedure OnMove(var Msg: TWMMove); message WM_MOVE, be sure to let it call inherited first as well). Truly a hack as well, but safer than the original hack.
